# Losing indicator applet complete from my panel

Tags: 18.04, indicator, ubuntu-mate, panel, applet

Sometimes I lose the indicator applet complete from my panel.

I looked in syslog, but there is no entry showing it closing down.

I need help diagnosing how to fix that problem.

Comment: Try to monitor `~/.xsession-errors` .